# ASP.net SqlDataSource.Update button with AJAX

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, sqldatasource

I cannot figure out how to use SqlDataSource.Update() in an `UpdatePanel` to avoid a page refresh. Here is the application structure:

`Div` click event calls `ASP:Button` > `ASP:Button` OnClick event calls SqlDataSource.Update() code behind > DB column is updated

I am trying to do all this without refreshing the page. Here is my code:

Default.aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true"/>

    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Enabled="True" />

    <div class="square" id="myId" runat="server">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="table-cell">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="myBtn" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="myBtn" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="my_Click" />
                            <p id="MyText" class="p">Unavailable for Dispatch</p>
                            <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="Grid" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataKeyNames="PhysicalAddress">
                                <Fields>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OwnerName" HeaderText="OwnerName" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="OwnerName">
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Building" HeaderText="Building" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="Building" ItemStyle-CssClass="building">
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeOn" HeaderText="TimeOn" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="TimeOn">
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="IPAddress" HeaderText="IPAddress" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="IPAddress" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide">
                                        <ControlStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PhysicalAddress" HeaderText="PhysicalAddress" ShowHeader="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PhysicalAddress" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide">
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="hide" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Available" HeaderText="Available" ShowHeader="False" SortExpression="Available" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide">
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="hide" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                </Fields>
                                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:DetailsView>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyDbConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [OwnerName], [Building], [TimeOn], [IPAddress], [PhysicalAddress], [Available] FROM [MyDb] WHERE ([OwnerName] = @OwnerName)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [MyDb] SET [Available] = CASE WHEN Available = '0' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END WHERE ([OwnerName] = @OwnerName)"> <SelectParameters> <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="My Name" Name="OwnerName" Type="String" /> </SelectParameters> <UpdateParameters> <asp:Parameter Name="OwnerName" /> </UpdateParameters> </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

jQuery `Div` click event:

```
$('#myId').on('click', (function (clickEvent) {

    document.getElementById("myBtn").click();

    })
)
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
    protected void my_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["OwnerName"].DefaultValue = "My Name";
    SqlDataSource1.Update();
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Bear in mind that all of this does work, but not without refreshing the entire page after ADO.NET event. Here is the event Output:

[image]

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at my event output posted above and answered my own question.

I changed my code-behind to:

```
    protected void my_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["OwnerName"].DefaultValue = "My Name";
SqlDataSource1.Update();}
```

...and of course I am no longer called the Response.Redirect. It is working as expected now.

Thank you!